# GKLeaderboard only shows data from friends, and resets every couple of hours

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I developed a game and wanted to add a Leaderboard. 
So I added a leaderboard in AppConnect and called in my code. 
I tought it was working, but the load scores function only returns scores of friend, and in a few hours it seems to reset. So my guess it only returns data from the last couple of hours and only from friends.

```
    let leaderboard = GKLeaderboard()
    leaderboard.identifier = "jetpackjoeleaderboard"
    leaderboard.playerScope = .global
    leaderboard.timeScope = .allTime

    leaderboard.loadScores { scores, error in
    guard let scores = scores else { return }
    for score in scores {
       // code for displaying the scores
    }
```

Anyone knows why this is happening ? Did I miss a setting>

In appConnect I can access the leaderboard and see the top 10 scores.

Thanks!

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/jetpack-joe/id1503990616?l=nl&ls=1
-Trystian

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue.
It just takes a couple of days, then it is returning data.